# ¿Como hago esta consulta en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, datatables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito llegar al Resultado anterior y no he podido.

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas intentado y específica de todas esas etiquetas en cuál base de datos trabajas

Comment: Bienvenido Julio a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con esta consulta

```
SELECT T0.NAME,COUNT(T1.ID) from AUTHOR T0
LEFT JOIN BOOK T1 ON T0.ID = T1.AUTHOR_ID
GROUP BY T0.NAME
```

Suponiendo que tienes un motor de base de datos MySql o SqlServer

Lo que se necesita hacer es una combinación de tablas, las cuales por medio de un campo en común podemos relacionarlas con la sentencia **JOIN**. El resultado de esta nos dará todos los campos que coincidan con la relación `AUTHOR.ID = BOOK.AUTHOR_ID`.

Usé el **LEFT JOIN** dado a que puede presentarse un AUTHOR sin registros en la tabla de BOOK lo que descartaría a ciertos autores del resultado final si se usara un **INNER JOIN**

Teniendo las tablas combinadas necesitamos contar cuantos datos se relacionan con el **campo NAME de la tabla AUTHOR**, para eso necesitamos una función de agregación **GROUP BY** que le indique al motor que agrupará por el campo que le indiquemos, en este caso `GROUP BY T0.NAME`

Teniendo la agrupación seleccionamos `SELECT T0.NAME,COUNT(T1.ID)` donde la función **COUNT** puede funcionar para contar los ID de la tabla BOOK y que sean agrupados por el campo NAME de AUTHOR por el `GROUP BY` entregando el resultado que se busca.

Comment: Agrego una explicación de la construcción de la consulta. Aun no se identificar si una pregunta se cerrará o no, si no me fui por el lado de que se podía responder, tendré mas cuidado la próxima.

Comment: No entiendo algunos usuarios de la comunidad por qué evalúa mal esta respuesta

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
AUT.NAME AS autor,
(COUNT(BOK.id)) AS libros
FROM AUTHOR AUT
INNER JOIN BOOK AS BOK
ON AUT.id = BOK.AUTHOR_ID
GROUP BY AUT.id
```

Comment: Si bien el código puede que sea la solución adecuada a la pregunta, te recomiendo leer [answer]. Más aún viendo, que quien ha preguntado, no ha sido capaz de llegar a realizar la query. Una idea de porque resuelve tú solución la misma, seguro que le vendría muy bien.

Comment: Agregar una explicacion para que la respuesta sea aceptada y no borrada.